# Why webpage running much slower in IE than in Firefox?

Tags: html

when I running one asp.net web site, there is one page is running very slow in IE, but other pages are running ok. It' wired that this page is running ok in firefox. Is there someone know the problem is? thanks!!! I am using Asp.net and js on that page

Comment: Probably going to need more information Dirk... What does the response look like, what technologies are you using, any significant amount of javascript?

Comment: Is this a web page you're creating, or does this belong on Superuser?

Comment: Have you checked for leaks? for `dom` insertion order problems in IE?

Answer (score 6):

Is the page JavaScript intensive? JS in IE is [notably](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-performance-rundown/) [slower](http://celtickane.com/labs/web-browser-javascript-benchmark/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The fact is I am using a module which is contain the js. how can I apply the timeout fuction to this module. Thanks.

Comment: The other important issue is that I can not access the module source code.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Andy Gaskell answer. IE only can get 2 resources at a time (images, css, js, whatever) , while FF gets 4. So, for the same given page Firefox will be able to download it faster than IE (granted that there is enough bandwidth)
Also, Firefox supports http pipelining wich accelerate things even more if the server supports http 1.1. It's disabled by default because supposedly it can have problems with some old servers, But the truth is I'm using it since Firefox 0.4 and never had an issue.

Comment: Note that IE can only get 2 resources at a time from a single unique domain. If you distribute your resources (images, css, js, etc.) accross several different distinct domains (content1.whatever.com, content2.whatever.com, content3.whatever.com), IE can stream 2 resources at a time from each domain. This is true even if all the domains point to the same physical server (IP). This is also true of other browsers, including FF and Opera.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to write about that